# scikit-learn clustering: predict(X) vs. fit_predict(X)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

In scikit-learn, some clustering algorithms have both `predict(X)` and `fit_predict(X)` methods, like *KMeans* and *MeanShift*, while others only have the latter, like *SpectralClustering*. According to the doc:

```
fit_predict(X[, y]):    Performs clustering on X and returns cluster labels.
predict(X): Predict the closest cluster each sample in X belongs to.
```

I don't really understand the difference between the two, they seem equivalent to me.

Comment: does predict returns the same thing as kmeans.labels_ or more accurate ones ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In order to use the 'predict' you must use the 'fit' method first. So using 'fit()' and then 'predict()' is definitely the same as using 'fit_predict()'. However, one could benefit from using only 'fit()' in such cases where you need to know the initialization parameters of your models rather than if you use 'fit_predict()', where you will just be obtained the labeling results of running your model on the data.

Comment: this doesn't quite answer the question. they're asking "why does `KMeans` have a `predict` method, but `SpectralClustering` doesn't ... and i actually can't work out the answer to this ... maybe it's a bug/missing feature? my understanding is that as part of the scikit-learn API design  all classifiers should have a `fit` and a `predict` method ...

Comment: Yeah, you are right. My answer was going more towards the 'I don't really understand the difference between the two, they seem equivalent to me.' part.

Comment: So... do we have an answer to @maxymoo 's question?

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 8):

`fit_predict` is usually used for unsupervised machine learning transductive estimator.

Basically, `fit_predict(x)` is equivalent to `fit(x).predict(x)`.

Comment: from a comp-sci point of view `fit()` will affect the state of your object/model yes/no? where as `predict()` will use the existing model to label the input data (and no change will be made to the object/model, yes/no?

Answer (score 2):

This might be very late to add an answer here, It just that someone might get benefitted  in future

The reason I could relate for having predict in kmeans and only fit_predict in dbscan is

- In kmeans you get centroids based on the number of clusters considered. So once you trained your datapoints using `fit()`, you can use that to `predict()` a new single datapoint to assign to a specific cluster.
- In dbscan you don't have centroids , based on the `min_samples` and `eps` (min distance between two points to be considered as neighbors) you define, clusters are formed . This algorithm returns cluster labels for all the datapoints. This behavior explains why there is no predict() method to predict a single datapoint. Difference between fit() and fit_predict() was already explained by other user -

In another spatial clustering algorithm hdbscan gives us an option to predict using `approximate_predict()`. Its worth to explore that.

Again its my understanding based on the source code I explored. Any experts can highlight any difference.